# (com.example.shonicserver.model.Product is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I get an error when I want return ProductByid. How to solve this error?

Model class

```
public class Product {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "name",  unique = true)
private String name;

@Column(name = "price" )
private Integer price;

@Column(name = "qty",  length = 3)
private Integer qty;

@Column(name = "date")
private String date;


@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private Categories categories;


@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
private Brand brand;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<FlashSale> discount;

@Column(name = "image")
private String image;

@Column(name = "image_full")
private Boolean imageFull;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Rating> ratingList;
```

Controller class

```
@GetMapping("getById/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Response> getOneProduct(@PathVariable UUID id) {
    List<Product> product=this.productService.findById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new Response(201,"succsess",product,null),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

ServiceImpl class

```
public List<Product> findById(UUID id) {
  Optional<Product> optionalProduct = productRepository.findById(id);
    Product product;
     if(optionalProduct.isPresent()) {
        product=optionalProduct.get();
        return (List<Product>) product;
        } else {
           return null;
        }

}
```

> error
> 2022-06-18 06:57:19.170 ERROR 9988 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.shonicserver.model.Product cannot be cast to class java.util.List (com.example.shonicserver.model.Product is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')] with root cause
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.shonicserver.model.Product cannot be cast to class java.util.List (com.example.shonicserver.model.Product is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not shared your `ProductRepository` here and it is just a guess based on your error log.

It seems that you have something like this in your repository class:

```
Optional<List<Product>> findById(UUID id);
```

But in your service layer you are trying to fetch data like this:

```
Optional<Product> optionalProduct = productRepository.findById(id);
```

And because you are using `UUID` I think that it is impossible to expect a `List<Product>` and you will only expect a single `Product`, so what you need to do is only changing your method in your repository layer to :

```
Optional<Product> findById(UUID id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your Product Id is UUID, then every product will have unique Id. So as per the given error says, `findById` only return one product entity, but you try to get `List<Product>`. you can't cast product into List as in your code.

There are 2 ways to fix this.

1. **Change the return type of `findById(UUID id)` from `List<Product>` to `Product`** since `productRepository.findById(id)` only return one `Optional<Product>`.

   ```
   // Controller
   @GetMapping("getById/{id}")
   public ResponseEntity<Response> getOneProduct(@PathVariable UUID id) {
   Product product=this.productService.findById(id);
   return new ResponseEntity<>(new Response(201,"succsess",product,null),HttpStatus.OK);
   }

   // ServiceImpl class
   public Product findById(UUID id) {
   Optional<Product> optionalProduct = productRepository.findById(id);
    if(optionalProduct.isPresent()) {
       return optionalProduct.get();

       } else {
          return null;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Second way is if you want to return the Product as a list then **convert the `optionalProduct` you get in the service into List and return that list**.

   ```
   public List<Product> findById(UUID id) {
       Optional<Product> optionalProduct = productRepository.findById(id);
        if(optionalProduct.isPresent()) {
           Product pr = optionalProduct.get();
           // Add Product to list and return that list.
           return Stream.of(pr).collect(Collectors.toList())
           } else {
              return null;
           }

       }
   ```

Hope this will solve your problem.